# Crashlytics gradle crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease and Android app bundle

Tags: gradle, crashlytics, android-app-bundle

Crashlytics NDK instructs to execute gradle crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease to upload native symbols. This task generates a full APK package for release build then uploads native symbols. Now I started using Android App Bundle (.aab) builds, and it is not clear how this task could be integrated automatically into AAB build process. Is this possible, or do I have to make 2 builds now, one for AAB, the other to simply upload native symbols to Crashlytics?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - what version of our Gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Thank you for responding, Mike! I have classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1', so looks like it's the latest one. Does it maybe upload NDK symbols automatically when any build is done? Or should I still execute manually 'gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease'?

Comment: @MikeBonnell It would be great if the plugin could add uploading the symbols to the build task tree, the way it does with `crashlyticsUploadDeobs`

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: No, if I build AAB, I also build APK with crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease task. It seems that Fabric and Crashlytics are on the way out, Google wants to replace them completely with Firebase, which at the moment is not quite ready.